# Correct an invalid Json string and convert it to C# Class

Tags: c#, json, class, json.net, typeconverter

I want to convert the following json string to a C# class. But i cant figure it out... even with a online converter programm like "json2csharp".

```
{[
  {
    "tmcp_post_fields": [],
    "product_id": 703,
    "per_product_pricing": true,
    "cpf_product_price": "45",
    "variation_id": false,
    "form_prefix": "",
    "tc_added_in_currency": "EUR",
    "tc_default_currency": "EUR"
  }
]}
```

Can someone help me?
I tried these false variations:

```
public class myclass
{
        public List<object> tmcp_post_fields { get; set; }
        public int product_id { get; set; }
        public bool per_product_pricing { get; set; }
        public string cpf_product_price { get; set; }
        public bool variation_id { get; set; }
        public string form_prefix { get; set; }
        public string tc_added_in_currency { get; set; }
        public string tc_default_currency { get; set; }
}
```

or a List of this class

```
List<myclass>
```

I use this code to convert it

```
if (value != null && value.GetType().FullName.StartsWith("Newtonsoft.Json"))
{
     string s = value.GetType().FullName;

     if (value.GetType().FullName.EndsWith("JArray"))
     {
           JArray ja = (JArray)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(JArray));

           if (ja.HasValues)
           {

                try
                {
                    return ja.ToObject<myclass>();       //this
                    return ja.ToObject<List<myclass>>(); //or this does NOT work for me
                }
                catch { }

                return value;
           }
           else
                return null;
}
```

I allway got this error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException - Error reading string. Unexpected
> token

If I remove the first opening and closing {} it would work.

Comment: Your top-level object has an array without a property name attached to it, so the JSON string isn't valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your json is not valid, it has extra {}  on the sides. Try this

```
var json=...your json

json=json.Substring(1,json.Length-2);

var jsonDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data[]>(json);
```

and class

```
public class Data
    {
        public List<object> tmcp_post_fields { get; set; }
        public int product_id { get; set; }
        public bool per_product_pricing { get; set; }
        public string cpf_product_price { get; set; }
        public bool variation_id { get; set; }
        public string form_prefix { get; set; }
        public string tc_added_in_currency { get; set; }
        public string tc_default_currency { get; set; }
    }
```

Another option is to use insert string. This option is even better since you can use parse json string as well.

```
json=json.Insert(1,"result:");
var jsonDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

and class

```
public class Root
{
    public Data[] result {get; set;}
}
```

output

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "tmcp_post_fields": [],
      "product_id": 703,
      "per_product_pricing": true,
      "cpf_product_price": "45",
      "variation_id": false,
      "form_prefix": "",
      "tc_added_in_currency": "EUR",
      "tc_default_currency": "EUR"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Its really help. I changed the title, so that other people can find it easier.